# R: the x overlap in the graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I visited this website to try to find the solution of the overlap problem.
The picture is extracted from  https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/3364_d1a578f521174152b46b19d0c83cbe7e.html
However, I still do not know how to solve it.

Image: overlap
[image]

My expected image:
[image]

I noted some solution of the axis.text.x overlap such as using `scale_x_discrete(labels = abbreviate)` to cut the words or using 
`axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)`,but it does not my expectation. Can you share your problem-solving suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: `ggplot(...) + theme( axis.text.x = element_text( size=10, color="gray" ) )`? Play with `size` parameter until you don't see overlap.

Comment: Apart from changing the theme size, could I change the interval of x? since I hope the text, which is big, is good for reading.

Comment: Yes. Stretch out the window of your plot and the intervals will be adjusted automatically. When saving to a file you can use `ggsave( ..., width = 10 )` to specify larger width of the plot area. While stretching the plot, you can use `geom_bar( ..., width = 0.5 )` to maintain the width of bars at a certain value.

Comment: Thank for your sharing. It might be a suitable solution. My text of x is around 4-8 characters, it will be easy to be overlapped. I have to set the width of ggsave to 14 and keep the text size in 1.5, which will not be too small, and then it will not overlap. However, the graph becomes too bigger if I put them on the website. Thank for your additional suggestion for me to change the size when I want.

Comment: No problem. I supposed I should put this information into a formal answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task can be formulated as fitting some amount of text onto some amount of plotting space. This can be approached by manipulating either the size of the text, or the size of the plotting area. The text size can be modified in `theme`:

```
ggplot(...) + theme( axis.text.x = element_text(size=10) )
```

while the plotting area size is specified as a parameter to `ggsave`:

```
ggsave(..., width=10)
```

Stretching the plot this way can lead to undesirable effect of bars stretching out. This can be compensated for by specifying a different `width` value in `geom_bar`:

```
ggplot(...) + geom_bar( ..., width=0.5 )
```